# Why Java allows casting obj with Interface

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

I have this exemple, i can t understand why java allows casting an obj with an interface who doesn't implement it.

```
public interface Interface {
  public void whoIam();
}

public class SuperClass {
}


public class SubClass extends SuperClass implements Interface {

public void whoIam() {
    System.out.println("I M a SubClass");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SuperClass a = new SubClass();


    Interface b = new SubClass();

    Interface c = (Interface) new SuperClass(); 
    c.whoIam();

}
```

This line below shouldn't compile because SuperClass doesn't implement the interface :

```
 Interface c = (Interface) new SuperClass();
```

It will generate "java.lang.ClassCastException:"

So, i think there is a reason that the compiler allows this line.

I would like to know when we can cast an obj with an interface when it doesn't implement it.

Thxs

Comment: why shouldn´t it allow you to do so? you could safely cast `a` to `Interface,` and even cast Objects to whatever you want, if any of the inheriting class does implement `Interface`. That´s what the `instanceof` keyword is made for...

Comment: But i thought that the compiler was able to detect that the SuperClass doesn't implement the Interface. @KevinEsche

Comment: @Kikou, sometimes it would be able to do so, sometimes it wouldn't. Always accepting these casts (and defer the error to runtime) is the simplest specification of how it should work.